# How to Constraining Eager Loads With whereIn function Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

**How to pass controls to with function**

```
$controls = $project['records']->pluck('id');    
$domain = ProcessDomain::with(['
        process.subprocess.control' =>
        function ($query,$controls) {
            $query->whereIn ('id', $controls);
        }
])->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using anonymous function you can pass variable like this:

```
$message = 'Hello';
// Inherit $message
$example = function () use ($message) {
    var_dump($message);
};
$example();
```

In your case you can try:

```
$controls = $project['records']->pluck('id');
$domain = ProcessDomain::with(['process.subprocess.control' => function ($query) use ($controls) {
        $query->whereIn ('id', $controls);
    }])->get();
```